# VCBuild: Unable to load Property sheet

Tags: build, vcproj, vcbuild

VCBuild is failing to load a property sheet. How can I specify $(SolutionDir)?

```
>vcbuild /logfile:log.txt /rebuild "./Project1/Project1.vcproj"

The following error has occurred during XML parsing:
File: ./Project1/Project1.vcproj
Line: 26
Column: 4
Error Message:
Property sheet file '$(SolutionDir)Property Sheets\Project1.vsprops' was not found or failed to load.
The file './Project1/Project1.vcproj' has failed to load.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**this**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/915e0c76-8ecd-4a31-a5b2-aed5f3b0b4da/), it's not possible to use the $(SolutionDir) when building individual projects. To build individual projects, use devenv.

```
devenv "Solution1.sln" /project "Project1.vcproj" /rebuild Debug
```

**Edit**: [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172438/using-msbuild-to-compile-a-single-cpp-file/4172700#4172700) is a better answer.