# How do I compile a single source file within an MSVC project from the command line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, command-line, benchmarking, performance-testing

I'm about to start doing some benchmarking/testing of our builds, and I'd like to drive the whole thing from a command line. I am aware of `DevEnv` but am not convinced it can do what I want.

If I could have a single file built within a single project, I'd be happy.

Can this be done?

Comment: Start Visual Studio Command Prompt, use cl.exe and/or link.exe.

Comment: @Ajay: Thanks for the pointer -- I am aware of these tools but what I'd like to do is use them with the same settings as those found in a preexsting MSVC++ project for a given source file. Can that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magical incantation is as follows. Note that this has only been tested with VS 2010 - I have heard this is the first version of Visual Studio with this capability:

## The Incantation

```
<msbuild> <project> <settings> <file>
```

### Where

- `msbuild` is a path to `MSBuild.exe`. Usually this should be set up for you by the VS2010 `bat` file so the right one will end up in your `PATH`, but if not I found one at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe`
- `project` is the path to the `vcxproj` file within which your source file resides.
- `settings` include the following:

  - `/p:Configuration="Debug"` // or whatever your Configuration is
  - `/p:Platform=x64` // or x86
  - `/t:ClCompile` // to specify specifically you're looking to compile the file
- `file` is actually another setting:

  - `/p:SelectedFiles="path_to_file"`

## Notes

- For `<project>` I *had* to specify a project (`vcxproj`) file instead of a solution (`sln`) file. The `sln` I would have used has multiple projects within it, so there would have been extra work to go that route anyhow (if it can even be done).
- For the `/p:Platform=x64` setting, there are several environment variables that pivot on what platform you are targeting (x64 v. x86) so make sure you set those up properly via Visual Studio's `vcvarsall.bat`.
- Regarding `path_to_file` in the `SelectedFiles` parameter, this path must be the path *as specified in the project file*. If the path does not match the path used in the project file to reference the source, it doesn't seem to work.